# Finding all files associated with an id within a folder of images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to populate a dataframe based on a class label and images in a folder.

I have a folder have over 10,000 images with the following name structure: `['leaflet_10000_1.jpg', 'leaflet_10000_2.jpg', 'leaflet_10001_1.jpg', 'leaflet_10001_2.jpg', 'leaflet_10002_1.jpg', 'leaflet_10002_2.jpg', 'leaflet_10003_1.jpg', 'leaflet_10003_2.jpg'`

And an accompanying csv file of the structure:

```
ID,Location,Party,Representative/Candidate,Date
1000,Glasgow North,Liberal Democrats,,02-Apr-10
1001,Erith and Thamesmead,Labour Party,,02-Apr-10
```

I want to create a new csv file which has the paths of all the images for a said `Party`. I can separate a certain party from the full csv file using the commands:

`df_ = df.loc[df["Party"] == "Labour Party"]`

This will give me the party I am interested in, but how do I create a FULL list of all images associated with it.. from the image list shared above, it can be seen that `ID 1001` has 2 images associated with it.. this is not a fixed number, some ID's have 3 to 5 images associated with them.

How do I get this new dataframe populated with all the required paths?

My thought process is to apply `str.split(name, '_')` on each file name and then search every ID against all the results but where to go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a dataframe of your images and extract the id.

```
from pathlib import Path

img_df = pd.DataFrame({'img' : [i.stem for i Path(your_images).glob('*.jpg')]})

img_df['ID'] = img_df['imgs'].astype(str).str.split('_',expand=True)[1].astype(int)

img_dfg = img_df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg(list)

      ID                                        imgs
0  10000  [leaflet_10000_1.jpg, leaflet_10000_2.jpg]
1  10001  [leaflet_10001_1.jpg, leaflet_10001_2.jpg]
2  10002  [leaflet_10002_1.jpg, leaflet_10002_2.jpg]
3  10003  [leaflet_10003_1.jpg, leaflet_10003_2.jpg]
```

then we just need to merge the ID columns.

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df,img_dfg,on='ID',how='left')
```

you can then do any further operations to group or list your images.

Comment: Thank you, the merged output is doing exactly what I want. But would it be possible to output the image names or paths in their own row with the associated Party rather than a list in a column?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track!

If all IDs are unique and you want an output dataframe with *just* the party and image number, you can do something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

partySer = df.loc[:, ['ID', 'Party']].set_index('ID')
# Get image names
imgFiles = list(Path('./<your-image-path>/').glob('*.jpg'))
imgFiles_str = np.array([str(f) for f in imgFiles])

# Grab just the integer ID from each image name
imgIds = np.array([int(f.stem.split('_')[1]) for f in imgFiles])

# Build dataframe with matching ids
outLst = []
for curId, party in partySer.iterrows():
  matchingImgIdxs = imgIds == curId
  matchingImgs = imgFiles_str[matchingImgIdxs]
  outLst.append({'Party': party, 'images': matchingImgs})

outDf = pd.DataFrame(outLst)
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should lead you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want in your DataFrame ? You said here that you wanted to populate your df with the required paths ? If so, then using the `str.split(name, '_')` would allow you to get the following information for every file : its ID, and its number.

You can now insert elements in your dataframe using both of these characteristics, adding any other characteristic obtained from the relative .csv file that you described. In the end, filtering the dataframe to get all elements that correspond to a given criteria should give you what you are looking for.

You seem to think that one ID will mean one line inside the dataframe, but its incorrect as each line is described by a (ID, number) in your case, and thus, your function would already give you the full list of all images associated with the party/ID/other characteristic.

If you want to reduce the size of your dataframe, since all images related to the same ID only have one characteristic that differ, you could also have a "Files" column, which contain a list of all images related to this ID (and thus, drop the "number" column), or just the number associated with them as their path is composed of the main path, followed by "_number.jpg". This solution would be a lot more efficient